# Tensorflow Exception in QueueRunner: Enqueue operation was cancelled

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm new to Tensorflow adn are trying to read images and labels. The code below works fine but every time it has finished it ends with producing an massive error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import os
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes

class DataSet():
    def __init__(self, path, info_train, info_test):
    self.image_path = path
    self.info_train = info_train
    self.info_test = info_test

def read_labeled_info(self):
    folder = self.image_path + "/"
    f = open(folder + self.info_train,"r")
    lines = f.readlines()
    fileNames = []
    landmarks = []
    attributes = []
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip("\n ").split(" ")
        if line == [""]:
            break
        fileNames.append(folder + line[0].replace("\\", "/"))
        coords = []
        for i in range(1,6):
            coords.append([float(line[i]),float(line[i+5])])
        attributes.append([int(line[i]) for i in range(11,15)])
        landmarks.append([coords])
    return fileNames, landmarks, attributes

def get_input_que(self):
    image_list, landmark_list, attribute_list = self.read_labeled_info()
    images_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_list, dtype=dtypes.string)
    landmark_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(landmark_list, dtype=dtypes.float32)
    attribute_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(attribute_list, dtype=dtypes.int32)
    inputQue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images_tensor, landmark_tensor, attribute_tensor])
    return inputQue

def read_images_from_disk(self):
    input_que = self.get_input_que()
    landmarks = input_que[1]
    attributes = input_que[2]
    file_contents = tf.read_file(input_que[0])
    images = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents, channels=3)
    return images, landmarks, attributes
```

I test it using:

```
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
data = DataSet("some_location", "training.txt", "testing.txt")
images, landmarks, attributes = data.read_images_from_disk()
tf.train.start_queue_runners()

image = images.eval()
print(image.shape)

coord.request_stop()
coord.join(threads)
sess.close()
```

I can access the image but when the program finishes it produces the error:

```
    ERROR:tensorflow:Exception in QueueRunner: Enqueue operation was cancelled
     [[Node: input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/input_producer, input_producer/input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]

Caused by op 'input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 124, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 351, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/joar/Documents/deep_learning/Deep-learning-MTFL/code/test3.py", line 58, in <module>
    images, landmarks, attributes = data.read_images_from_disk()
  File "/home/joar/Documents/deep_learning/Deep-learning-MTFL/code/test3.py", line 41, in read_images_from_disk
    input_que = self.get_input_que()
  File "/home/joar/Documents/deep_learning/Deep-learning-MTFL/code/test3.py", line 37, in get_input_que
    inputQue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images_tensor, landmark_tensor, attribute_tensor])
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 307, in slice_input_producer
    shared_name=shared_name)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 264, in range_input_producer
    shared_name, "fraction_of_%d_full" % capacity, name)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 164, in input_producer
    enq = q.enqueue_many([input_tensor])
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 367, in enqueue_many
    self._queue_ref, vals, name=scope)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1556, in _queue_enqueue_many_v2
    name=name)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

CancelledError (see above for traceback): Enqueue operation was cancelled
     [[Node: input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/input_producer, input_producer/input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]
>>> 
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1039, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1021, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Enqueue operation was cancelled
     [[Node: input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/input_producer, input_producer/input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 234, in _run
    sess.run(enqueue_op)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 982, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1032, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1052, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.CancelledError: Enqueue operation was cancelled
     [[Node: input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/input_producer, input_producer/input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]

Caused by op 'input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany', defined at:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 124, in main
    ret = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/idlelib/run.py", line 351, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "/home/joar/Documents/deep_learning/Deep-learning-MTFL/code/test3.py", line 58, in <module>
    images, landmarks, attributes = data.read_images_from_disk()
  File "/home/joar/Documents/deep_learning/Deep-learning-MTFL/code/test3.py", line 41, in read_images_from_disk
    input_que = self.get_input_que()
  File "/home/joar/Documents/deep_learning/Deep-learning-MTFL/code/test3.py", line 37, in get_input_que
    inputQue = tf.train.slice_input_producer([images_tensor, landmark_tensor, attribute_tensor])
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 307, in slice_input_producer
    shared_name=shared_name)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 264, in range_input_producer
    shared_name, "fraction_of_%d_full" % capacity, name)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/input.py", line 164, in input_producer
    enq = q.enqueue_many([input_tensor])
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 367, in enqueue_many
    self._queue_ref, vals, name=scope)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 1556, in _queue_enqueue_many_v2
    name=name)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/joar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

CancelledError (see above for traceback): Enqueue operation was cancelled
     [[Node: input_producer/input_producer/input_producer_EnqueueMany = QueueEnqueueManyV2[Tcomponents=[DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](input_producer/input_producer, input_producer/input_producer/RandomShuffle)]]
```

I don't am stuck on this so any help would be much appriciated

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by updating

```
tf.train.start_queue_runners()
```

to

```
tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, the `QueueRunner` API has been deprecated and replaced by [tf.data](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets).